# Выражение "спустя время" и его применение

Tags: стилистика

Добрый день, может, кто-то знает точно?

В письме прочла выражение: "И только спустя более года мой дизайнер"... Что-то мне подсказывает, что так неправильно. Нарушена "связь времен". Или "спустя время" или "прошло более года, прежде чем я узнал (понял) и т. д."...

Или я не права?

Answer (score 4):

```
 Что-то мне подсказывает
```

Это что-то-языковая интуиция. Это не ошибка, лексическая сочетаемость в порядке, а вот грамматическая "корявость"есть. Нарушена не  "связь времен", а грамматическая связь, управление. Предлог "спустя" требует вин. пад.существительного, а не сравнительную степень. Хотя в разговорном варианте фраза возможна как своеобразный сокращённый вариант: "И только спустя какое-то время,где-то более года, мой дизайнер...".

Comment: _Предлог "спустя" требует вин. пад. существительного..._ === **Существительного ли?**  А какое существительное стоит в **винительном** падеже, к примеру, здесь: _"спустя несколько дней..."_?

Comment: "А еще через годик она ссорится за что-нибудь с своими хозяевами и переходит на другое место, с которого спустя более или менее непродолжительное время перебегает на третье, на четвертое,  [И. Т. Кокорев. Кухарка (1849). "Я же о сем случае узнал спустя более недели и потому не доводил до сведения начальника зная, что его этим можно встревожить и поколебать его храбрость. [А. К. Карпов. Записки (1831)]

Answer (score 2):

Спустя год - это через год, например:

Спустя год после моей встречи с Каратаевым случилось мне заехать в Москву (И. С. Тургенев).

Answer (score 1):

> спустя более...

[Так говорят.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%22&tbm=bks)

В т. ч.

академик Дмитрий Сергеевич Лихачев: ***"спустя более полутысячелетия..."***

академик Виктор Владимирович Виноградов: ***"спустя более семидесяти лет..."***

===============

> "И только спустя более года мой дизайнер"... Что-то мне подсказывает,
>   что так неправильно. Или я не права?

Да, не правы. И не только Вы...

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы, это звучит ужасно. Лучше будет так - "И лишь спустя год с небольшим" или "Прошло больше года, и только тогда мой дизайнер..." И т.д.

Comment: Это является ответом на вопрос. Автор спрашивает, права ли она в том, что фраза сформулирована некорректно. И я отвечаю да. А потом даю пару вариантов улучшения.

Comment: Хороший ответ, но на мой взгляд, немножко обоснований и примеров.

Answer (score 0):

Самое близкое из корректного: "спустя более чем год". Но и это не для всего контекста и стиля речи. Остальное - у Людмилы.

Что касается конструкций, найденных и Лихачева и Виноградова, то Лихачев иногда допускал чересчур разговорные конструкции, водилось за ним такое. Возможно это следствие записи устной речи.

Вот с Виноградовым надо бы контекст смотреть. Во всяком случае "ссылка на гугл" не слишком убедительна.